# unable to get the multi parameter values using ng bootstrap modal using angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

Here im creating the dynamic buttons and by using the button values im sending those values to the ng bootstrap modal here i m able to send and retrieve one value only i unable to send multiple values and how can i display it in the input in the modal below is my code :

NOte: Here im getting only **Id** in the modal but im also sending the name and id

.html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let info of Data">

                <div *ngIf="info.State==='1'" >
                  <button [id]="info.Id" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)=onOne(info.Id,info.Name)>
                    {{info.Name}}
                  </button>
                </div>


              </ng-container>
```

Below is my TS code

```
onOne(content,data) {
    this.modalService.open(content,data).result.then((result) => {
      debugger;

      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;

    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return  `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The second one should be options which has to be handled as object and not a variable.

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(content);
modalRef.componentInstance.data= data;
modalRef.result.then((data) => {....
```

will hopefully work.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Also it is not doable if your content is a string, you need to pass the content as templateRef to make it work. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api

Comment: like this i have to insert onDriverOne(content,data) {

    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(content);
modalRef.componentInstance.data= data;
modalRef.result.then((data) => {

  this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
},(reason) => {
       this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });


  }

Answer (score 0):

you just have to send info

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let info of Data">

                <div *ngIf="info.State==='1'" >
                  <button [id]="info.Id" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)=puchInfo(info)>
                    {{info.Name}}
                  </button>
                </div>


              </ng-container>
```

and you can push the data in back end side

```
infoList=[];
puchInfo(info){

this.infoList.push(info);

}
```

and then u can call your function inside info

if any query please ask in comment

Comment: here we are pushing data but i want to open it in the modal

Comment: after pushing data you can use ng-modal and use inner-html  you can display data